# How to Pass Weights of Edges to the Weight Argument of a Networkx Function

Tags: python, networkx

The function in particular is edge_betweeness_centrality. One of the graphs I'm trying to get the edge betweeness of is a weighted graph. My question is how would I be able to supply the function the weights of every edge in the graph? Pretty much I'm always dealing with unweighted graphs so normally I can always leave the weight argument to the default value of none, but this is the first time I'm dealing with a weighted graph. I guess this also extends to any function that takes the weight of a graph as an argument when working with a weighted graph.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Passing edges with weights in networkx can be done in this way.

```py
import networkx as nx

# Creating the graph
G = nx.Graph()

#Creating the list of weighted edges
elist = [('a','b', 5.0), ('b','c',3.0), ('c','d',7.3)]
# Adding them to the graph
G.add_weighted_edges_from(elist)

#Calling edge_betweenness_centrality
nx.edge_betweenness_centrality(G, weight='weight')
```

Output:

```py
{('a', 'b'): 0.5, ('b', 'c'): 0.6666666666666666, ('c', 'd'): 0.5}
```

From the [documentation](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.centrality.edge_betweenness_centrality.html#networkx.algorithms.centrality.edge_betweenness_centrality)

> **weight**:  (None or string, optional (default=None)) – If None, all edge weights are considered equal. Otherwise holds the name of the
> edge attribute used as weight.

This links will help you in a future [documentation](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.centrality.edge_betweenness_centrality.html#networkx.algorithms.centrality.edge_betweenness_centrality) and [examples](https://www.programcreek.com/python/example/89598/networkx.betweenness_centrality). This examples are with `betweenness_centrality`, but can be applied also to the function that you ask for. Also in general with networkx, you can pass a list of weighted edges in that way, for more info refer to the [documentation](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/tutorial.html#edges).

Comment: Thanks! This solved the issue. Thanks for the links as well. I'll definitely put those to good use